# Контент съезжает под слайдер

Tags: css

html:

[image]

```
.slider {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Добавь слайдеру фиксированную высоту или убери абсолютное позиционирование. Все, что можно предположить по такому количеству данных.

Comment: @rodion, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: `.content {
  padding-top:  {высота слайдера} px;
}`

Comment: Контент съезжает под слайдер, а не должен если .slider {position: absolute;}? Что хочешь то?